# How to change Windows ACL 'Group' with Powershell?

Tags: wcf, powershell

Problem:
I need to limit access to a WCF service using only Windows account settings. I have a WCF service with security binding element 'clientCredentialType' set to 'Windows'. Can't change this setting. If I understand correctly, anyone with an authentic windows account is authorized as long as they meet the authorization rules set by the file (EXE) that is hosting that WCF service. So I went into Powershell and queried the settings for that service:

```
Get-Acl MYSERVICE.exe | Format-List
```

says:

```
Path   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Program Files (x86)\Blah\Server\MYSERVICE.exe
Owner  : BUILTIN\Administrators
Group  : MYDOMAIN\Domain Users
Access : NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM Allow  FullControl
     BUILTIN\Administrators Allow  FullControl
     BUILTIN\Users Allow  ReadAndExecute, Synchronize
     APPLICATION PACKAGE AUTHORITY\ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES Allow  ReadAndExecute, Synchronize
Audit  :
Sddl   : O:BAG:DUD:AI(A;ID;FA;;;SY)(A;ID;FA;;;BA)(A;ID;0x1200a9;;;BU)(A;ID;0x1200a9;;;AC)
```

Every user in my domain seems to have access.

**Question, how do I change 'MYDOMAIN\Domain Users' to a different group in my domain so that every domain user (in that group) does not have access?**

I have been able to change the list of accounts and their permissions under 'Access' like this:

```
$perm = "My Other Domain Group","FullControl","Allow"
$rule=New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule $perm
$myservice_acl.SetAccessRule($rule)
```

And can presumably explicitly deny or grant access but how do I change the group it inherits from? Or is this the correct approach?

Comment: Your ACL doesn't have an ACE with the identity reference `MYDOMAIN\Domain Users`. Do you want to change the *group* of the security descriptor? Why?

Comment: A process on another users machine (running under their domain account in MYDOMAIN) has access to this service running on my machine. I want to know how I can block their access to this service by changing the ACL, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows Security Descriptor(SD) is broken up into four primary parts:

1. Owner
2. Group (or Primary Group)
3. Discretionary Access Control List (DACL)
4. System Access Control List (SACL)

**The Primary Group part of the SD is ignored and has been ignored since Windows 2000** and was preserved for backwards compatability with POSIX operating systems. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961983.aspx

For your case, the only two fields to concern yourself with are the Owner and the DACL.

- The Owner has implicit Full Control over the Securable Object.
- The DACL is a list of Access Control Entries (ACEs) which defines Security Identifiers (SIDs or trustees) that have a level of access rights defined.

In other words, if you are concerned about the SD on your service binary, check the owner and all members of the DACL but not the Primary Group.

- https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961983.aspx
- https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781716(v=ws.10).aspx
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379563(v=vs.85).aspx

EDIT:  For the sake of completeness, the SACL is a list of ACEs (trustees and access rights) but instead of governing control, it controls who is audited and for what type of behavior.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Group: The security group of the owner.
```

only users in following groups are able to reach folder\object:

```
NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM Allow  FullControl,
BUILTIN\Administrators Allow  FullControl,
BUILTIN\Users Allow  ReadAndExecute, Synchronize,
```

you should check only access property to add/remove/query who has access to the folder\file

Comment: Looks like this is correct. I managed to change the group with SetGroup and it had no effect. Just confused because if I understand correctly all three of those ACE are only relevant the local machine. The service that these ACL settings are on is still accessible from a process running under a domain account on a remote machine. I would think that since every ACE on that list is local, the other domain user on the remote machine would have no access.

Comment: correct if this folder is not shared - ntfs applies only to the local boundary.
if I helped please mark this as answer - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Domain users have access via the local group `BUILTIN\Users` (joining a computer to a domain automatically adds the group `DOMAIN\Domain Users` to the group `BUILTIN\Users` on the joining host). The group property of the security identifier has nothing to do with the access.

If you want to prevent access by domain users in general and allow just a particular domain group you'd remove the `DOMAIN\Domain Users` ACE and add an ACE for the desired group:

```
$ace = $myservice_acl.Access |
       Where-Object { $_.IdentityReference -eq 'DOMAIN\Domain Users' }
$myservice_acl.RemoveAccessRule($ace)

$ace = New-Object Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule ('DOMAIN\Other Group', 'FullControl', 'Allow')
$myservice_acl.AddAccessRule($ace)

Set-Acl -AclObject $myservice_acl -Path ...
```

If you just want to deny access to a particular user you could also create a deny ACE for that user. However, mixing permissions like that tends to become pretty messy pretty fast, so I wouldn't recommend going this route.